# Get value of JSONArray by string index?

Tags: android, get, arrays

my JSONArray does not have numeric indexes. I need to get them anyhow like
`jArray.get("myIndexHere");` but how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

For instance, if every element of your `JSONArray` is a `JSONbject`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jArray.optJSONObject(i);
    if (obj != null) {} 
 }
```